# Instantiate two different players objects on network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

I am using two different objects for player in network multiplayer game. Two different kinds of Gameobject will be instantiated by unity [network Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html) but the problem is there is only single property of [playerprefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html). How can i set two different objects even i tried to change it on run time but its giving me error.

> Failed to spawn server object,
>   assetId=4d293c8e162f3874b982baadd71153d2 netId=1
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()
>
> Failed to spawn server object,
>   assetId=4d293c8e162f3874b982baadd71153d2 netId=7
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of UNetManager:

> if you want to customize the way player GameObjects are created, you can override that virtual function. This code shows an example of the default implementation:

```
public virtual void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
{
    var player = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(playerPrefab, playerSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, player, playerControllerId);
}
```

You could change the prefab inside that code to the prefab you want to spawn.

Hope this helps you with your problem of choosing which prefab.

Comment: OnserverAddPlayer event is not executing and will this allow to instantiate different player objects?

Comment: in fact how did you resolve this approach, @MuhammadFaizanKhan ?!